# Need a head-start for new topics in maths

Tags: number-theory, soft-question

I am a maths enthusiast ( but from electrical engineering background ) . In my college I had two math courses on differential and integral calculus and I had choosen an elective in complex-analysis . I dont have the opportunity of availing any other math courses in my remaining college life , but I want to learn more .

I now want to move into the realm of topics like number theory , advanced algebra . I feel that these topics are more challenging and stimulating compared to that of calculus .

Could someone please help me out with the possible list of books/resources for the given topics .

Comment: please also tell me the pre-requisites for these things .

Comment: Since you seem to be looking to learn from textbooks, but you don't have a lot of experience with textbooks from college, let me give you a tiny piece of advice, ripped from Shelden Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*. "You cannot expect to read mathematics the way you read a novel. If you zip through a page in less than an hour, you are probably going too fast." (Oh, and you might also consider reading Shelden Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* :P )

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw : Ditto what Eric said, you learn much more from reading books and doing problems than from just reading books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fantastic book to begin your studies in Abstract Algebra is "*A Book of Abstract Algebra*" by Charles Pinter. It is a Dover publication that can be purchased inexpensively. The prerequisites are minimal; the writing style is clear. It is an extremely enjoyable text!

Answer (score 1):

A textbook that I quite like for abstract algebra is *Abstract Algebra: An Introduction* by Thomas Hungerford. It is a book that approaches the subject at a level that a college junior who understands maths should be able to digest. At my university, we use commonly use this book as an introductory book to modern algebra, right after a student takes multivariable calculus. The reader would need to have a basic linear algebra course to use this book, but that is going to be true with any algebra book.

If you want a really holistic approach to the subject of algebra, maybe try a book by Herstein.

Another suggestion, if you are in for a more advanced text, is Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*. Prerequisites for D and F would be a decent understanding of the previously mentioned texts.

As for number theory, I used *Fundamentals of Number Theory* by W.J LeVeque. The Hungerford book would prepare you for this book.